# Why angular not detecting a method with ng promise return type?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Here is my code:
**Interface**

```
    export interface IConsignmentDataService {
      getConsignmentListData(): ng.IPromise<IConsignmentListViewModel>;
      filterConsignments(filters: Filter[]): ng.IPromise<IConsignmentListViewModel>;
    }
```

**Implementation**

```
export class ConsignmentDataService implements IConsignmentDataService {

    static $inject: string[] = ["$http", "$q"];

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService) {

    }

    getConsignmentListData(): ng.IPromise<IConsignmentListViewModel> {
        var defer = this.$q.defer();
        var apiUrl = "/Api/Consignments/AllConsignments";
        this.$http.get(apiUrl)
            .success((data: IConsignmentListViewModel) => {
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .error((reason: string) => {
                defer.reject(reason);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    }

    filterConsignments(filters: Filter[]): ng.IPromise<IConsignmentListViewModel> {
        var defer = this.$q.defer();
        var url = "/Api/Consignments/FilterConsignments";
        this.$http.post(url, { "filters": filters })
            .success((data: IConsignmentListViewModel) => {
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .error((reason: string) => {
                defer.reject(reason);
            });

        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

and this is how I am calling this:

```
refresh(): void {
    this.consignmentDataService.filterConsignments(this.currentFilters).then((data: IConsignmentListViewModel) => {
        console.log("success");
    }, () => {
        console.log("failure");
    });
}
```

The problem is, when I call `getConsignmentListData()` its working properly but when I call `filterConsignments` its giving error:
**Error: this.consignmentDataService.filterConsignments is not a function**
Please be ensured that the solution is building properly and the parameters are also populated nicely. I also tried to use a `console.log()` inside `filterConsignments` to check if it is getting called but no luck. It is always giving the error.

**Detailed Error Message:**

```
Error: this.consignmentDataService.filterConsignments is not a function
ConsignmentListController.prototype.refresh@http://localhost:8044/app/consignment/List/consignmentList.controller.js:145:21
ConsignmentListController@http://localhost:8044/app/consignment/List/consignmentList.controller.js:139:21
invoke@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:4478:14
instantiate@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:4486:27
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:9151:18
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular-route.js:977:26
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:8789:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:8289:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:7680:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:7555:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:7699:1
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:8316:18
update@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular-route.js:935:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:16311:15
commitRoute/<@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular-route.js:619:15
processQueue@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:14745:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:14761:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:15989:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:15800:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:16097:13
done@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:10546:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:10744:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:8044/Scripts/angular.js:10685:1

<div data-ng-animate="1" class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

Comment: not answer but 2 changes in code.. 1) dont use $defer, directly return $http.get result, so dont need $q... also 2) dont use success/failure, use then/catch, preferred way

Comment: @entre I do not completely understand what you suggested. Can you please give some more details?

Comment: change the code to `return this.$http.post(url, { "filters": filters })` you dont need $q and deferred stuff

Comment: Check out [the deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: I am not sure but the problem resolves when I manually deleted the corresponding .js files and generated them again. Thank you all for your help and support. Much appreciated.